# Can I still using android library that depends on jCenter after the jCenter deprecation?

Tags: android, jcenter, pdf-viewer

I have an app that displays pdf and I'm using barteksc android pdfviewer library:
`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'`

it depends on jcenter and jcenter is dperecated.
I have added jcenter and android studio display a warning that it is deprecated.
The question: Can I still use this library and publish my app safely despite jcenter deprecation?

Comment: jCenter will still serve packages till February 1st 2022. So, your app will still compile till that date. You can start the switch to a different library that's available on maven central. Maybe the author of this library would also migrate to maven central.

Comment: thanks. But the app still working fine after Feb 1st 2022??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still use it I know I'm 9 months late but you can first delete the jCenter because its deprecated then just add the following code in "settings.gradle" file:

```
gradlePluginPortal()
```